# Tunring an array of probabilities, into a binary array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, softmax

I am trying to convert a NumPy array of probabilities that sum up to 1.0, into a binary array. Essentially, I want to turn the max probability in the array into 1, and the rest into 0s. Of course, I know how to do this using Python, but I was hoping that NumPy or SciPy already come up with a built-in function for making the operation more performant (we are speaking about a matrix containing millions of such arrays).

Comment: Show your python code?

Comment: Please provide a small example to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare items with the maximum value, and cast to int

```
>>> a=np.array([0.435,0.24,0.241,0.13,0.56])

>>> np.int8( a == a.max() )
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1], dtype=int8)
```